# Is there a PHP 5.2 'compatibility mode' for PHP 5.3?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently developing a Wordpress plugin. I just became aware of the fact that most major Wordpress hosting environments are still using PHP 5.2. Given the fact that security patches for 5.2 are still being released despite the fact 5.2 is no longer officially supported, it very much looks like 5.2 isn't going anywhere soon.

So it looks like I'll need to do some refactoring where I've made use of a few 5.3 features, namely late static binding and closures.

Ideally I don't want to totally trash my 5.3 environment just to install a 5.2 one. Is there some way to set a 'compatibility mode' for my 5.3 setup so it only accepts valid 5.2 syntax?

Comment: Are security patches still being released for 5.2? I don't think there's been any new patches since 5.2 was declared end-of-life, and I don't believe that anyone has promised any either.

Comment: Development on 5.2 has stopped completely, even security patches won't be applied anymore. The last commit to the 5.2 branch was in March. Some distros may still do some maintenance, though (I'm not sure).

Comment: I was refering to this: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#Release_history
it seems the last release was 2011-01-06

Comment: Compatibility mode in PHP, which is sometimes not compatible between bugfix releases?

Comment: @James - yep the Wikipedia page is correct, 6th Jan was the last 5.2 release. It was decleared EOL in March.

Comment: Any hosting company still running 5.2 needs to reconsider, as they are giving themselves a serious liablility by running an unsupported version. If their distro provides back-ported patches then fair enough, but even that can't last for long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to do this, you'll have to install 5.2.

If you can live with catching only syntax level incompatibilities (`static::`, lambda functions, `goto`, ...), then you can have a 5.2 binary in an isolated location and run the syntax check on the files (`php -l`) as a build step. You won't get warned of usage of the new functions, new arguments, etc. though.